# IP Datagram Fragmentation total length and payload calculations

Tags: routing, ipv4, mtu, data, fragmentation

I do not understand how to fragment a IP datagram.

Let's say the original datagram has a total size of 302 (20bytes header and 282 bytes payload). My datagram needs to be fragmented since it goes through a network of 128MTU. I have to fragment it and add 20 header for each new fragments.

- Fragment 1 124 total length (104 bytes payload)
- Fragment 2 124 total length  (104 bytes payload)
- Fragment 3 94 total length  (74 bytes payload)

If I addition that it gives me indeed the original payload. I do not understand how to find those numbers...

Why couldn't it be

- Fragment 1 114 total length (94 bytes payload)
- Fragment 2 114 total length  (94 bytes payload)
- Fragment 3 114 total length  (94 bytes payload)

(282/128(MTU)) > 2 so I need 3 fragments. 3Fragments = 60 bytes header added
60 +282 = 342 342/3 = 114 total lenght for each fragments.

My question is...

How and why should I get 124 124 and 94?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP fragmentation and reassembly is described by the RFCs. You must fragment on 64-bit boundaries. There are RFCs dealing with this, and other sites which will describe the fragmentation and reassembly process in depth; you can do a search to find them

Start with [RFC 791, INTERNET PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791):

> To fragment a long internet datagram, an internet protocol module
> (for example, in a gateway), creates two new internet datagrams and
> copies the contents of the internet header fields from the long
> datagram into both new internet headers.  The data of the long
> datagram is divided into two portions on a 8 octet (64 bit) boundary
> (the second portion might not be an integral multiple of 8 octets,
> but the first must be).  Call the number of 8 octet blocks in the
> first portion NFB (for Number of Fragment Blocks).  The first
> portion of the data is placed in the first new internet datagram,
> and the total length field is set to the length of the first

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped for my comprehension. Didn't know about the rule.